# EVP_PKEY thread-safety with EVP_SealInit()/EVP_SealUpdate()/EVP_SealFinal()

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I have a public key (`EVP_PKEY`) which I read using `PEM_read_PUBKEY()`. I use this `EVP_PKEY` from several threads for performing envelope encryption with `EVP_SealInit()`/`EVP_SealUpdate()`/`EVP_SealFinal()`. Do I need a mutex for protecting the `EVP_PKEY` when using the EVP_SealXXXX() functions?

I am duplicating the key at the moment in my development environment with `EVP_PKEY_dup()` (which is protected by a mutex), but I don't know where it is needed. In production I have an older version of OpenSSL (1.1.1) and `EVP_PKEY_dup()` is not available.

Comment: In absence of explicit OpenSSL documentation stating that these functions are thread-safe, you betcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the OpenSSL documentation [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/openssl-threads.html) the generally the main theme that it is only thread-safe when working on separate handles.  For a singel handle then it's not thread-safe.

As this applies to the function calls you are using this part applies:

> The same API's can usually be used simultaneously on different objects
> without interference. For example, two threads can calculate a
> signature using two different EVP_PKEY_CTX objects.

So long as you use different EVP_PKEY_CTX per thread you should be thread safe.
Access to EVP_PKEY by the EVP_PKEY_CTX will be thread safe as it's only reading the key data.  So you shouldn't need to dup it.

Comment: When you say ```EVP_PKEY_CTX```, do you mean ```EVP_CIPHER_CTX```? Each thread creates its own ```EVP_CIPHER_CTX``` (```EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()```), which is then used when calling ```EVP_SealInit()```/```EVP_SealUpdate()```/```EVP_SealFinal()```. My confusion comes because ```pubk``` is not ```const``` in ```EVP_SealInit()```. I also think that these functions only need to read the key data, but I don't know whether they update something in ```pubk```.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot EVP_SealXxx uses EVP_CIPHER_CTX.  Yes it does apply to EVP_CIPHER_CTX as well.  So long as you don't modify the pubk ourself (EVP_PKEY_set1xxx functions) then you should be thread safe.